# Derivation of E step in EM algorithm

Tags: expectation-maximization, latent-semantic-analysis

While im going through the derivation of E step in EM algorithm for pLSA, i came across the following derivation [at this page](http://www.hongliangjie.com/2010/01/04/notes-on-probabilistic-latent-semantic-analysis-plsa/). Could anyone explain me how the following step is derived.

$\sum_z q(z) log \frac{P(X|z,\theta)P(z|\theta)}{q(z)}  = \sum_z q(z) log \frac{P(z|X,\theta)P(X,\theta)}{q(z)} $

Comment: It's all to do with Bayes Rule: I've explained it in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-q0KFRaPuvc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [Bayes' formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) :

$\Pr[A \mid B] = \frac{\Pr[B \mid A] \Pr[A]}{\Pr[B]}$

Here, it gives:
$\Pr[X \mid z, \theta] = \frac{\Pr[z \mid X, \theta] \Pr[X \mid \theta]}{\Pr[z \mid \theta]}$

Comment: if we substitute your $P[X|z,\theta)$, we will end up $P(z|X,\theta)P(X|\theta)$ but not = $P(z|X,\theta)P(X,\theta) $.

Comment: @Learner: Well... I have not read the document, but $\theta$ is the standard notation for a parameter. Now, a parameter is a fixed quantity, not a random variable, and it does not make sense to compute $P(\theta)$... Could it be a typo ?